Journal keeps messing with my proof
Our work was accepted at a prestigious Q1 journal. We have gone through the peer review process and we’re in the final state of correcting the proof. I heard that it, the journal, is bad at editing,... and turns out it is worse than I thought. We sent them the full LaTeX source and the PDF. They sent us the draft of the proof and there were font errors everywhere. They sent us a link to an online editing tool used for editing the proof and it was the laggiest thing I have ever used (it is like MS Word, but worse). I can't even properly add a reference if it is not published. It took me a few days to point out most of the errors for them to fix and they later sent us the second proof. So I decided to use their online tool to edit the proof, it took me almost a week to propagate modifications from our original LaTeX source to the proof. A few weeks later, everything was gone. So I contacted them along with a PDF file containing all modifications (I printed it out with Chrome). They looked at my PDF and applied the mods manually. They missed a few equations because the online tool can't track changes to equations. My supervisor was really upset for the second time. I went back to use the tool to apply the changes and implement some new ones. It took me another whole week just to propagate the changes, which took me only one day to implement using LaTeX. And guess what! A month later, all of my mods and my supervisor’s are gone. I am sure that they won't be able to recover our mods by merely looking at the PDF that I sent them (again, with most of the changes). I think my supervisor's tolerance is at its peak.
I am still at the early stage of my career and might have said that my work was going to be published in this particular journal here and there. I am sure we can have it published in another journal pretty easily. What are the possibilities that can happen to our work? I am really sick of using their online tool. Should I be afraid that the journal will reject us ?

Primarily just a rant.

Word is many things but laggy is not one of them

You haven't actually said who your advisor is upset with. Is it with you or with the journal? Are they a co-author of this work?

@AzorAhai-him- Word is many things, and laggy is definitely one of them, especially with long, complex documents.

Your advisor's tolerance is probably at a low point, not a peak (local maximum).

Please avoid answering in the comments.

What was the purpose of the online tool, if not to give them direct ready-to-print input?

This sounds like a very frustrating situation. What I would probably do at this point is to attempt to escalate handling of the case to higher-level staff or editorial members of the journal's team than the ones you have been communicating with so far. Ask to be put in touch with the editor in chief, managing editor, production editor, or someone of that stature who is experienced enough to understand your frustration and will be in a position to come up with a plan for fixing the situation. Explain the problem and ask for their help. If they tell you to just try using their crummy web software again, tell them that it's not working and has led you to waste a lot of your time already, and ask them to propose another solution.
I have had my own share of frustrations of similar types dealing with the publishing industry (though nothing as bad as what you're describing, fortunately). What seems to be happening is that book and journal publishers often try to cut costs by outsourcing important parts of their production work to faceless overseas companies. These third party contractors are usually competent at handling routine matters but can be completely clueless whenever any even slightly unusual issue presents itself. This is why it's important that you enlist someone on the inside from the journal itself, not from the third party contractor, to advocate for you and help you resolve the problem. Such a person will also understand that the journal's reputation is at stake and that it's not acceptable for a reputable journal to accept a paper and then completely mess up the actual publication process.
Good luck!

Talk directly to the chief editor about the situation. I had a similar experience when some overzealous technical editor decided to correct my (imperfect, but, I surmise, mostly understandable) English and changed the meanings of quite a few sentences with mathematical statements beyond recognition. I wrote to the chief editor directly (I did it in rhymed verse, but you don't need to go that far) and his quick decision was just to revert to the original version and publish it as it was. It helped a bit that the chief editor was a good acquaintance of one of my friends and co-authors, of course, but I think any reasonable editor should be able and willing to resolve the issue, and if not, just give up and resubmit elsewhere.

Any journal will have its own procedures for producing output. This assures some consistency over time. It also aids maintainability of the digital files. If you don't like to work with their tools you can complain, but probably without effect. You can withdraw your work and take it elsewhere and deal with the tools and processes of the other journal.
I suspect that a "prestigious" journal has usable tools or they wouldn't merit their reputation. I also suspect they are less likely to break their own, long standing, rules.
If the work has been accepted, it is not especially likely, though possible, that they will dump you. But fighting with them will delay publication.
If you have already signed over copyright to them then you have few options. I suggest you "grin and bear it".

I am ok with using their tool. The fact that it deletes all of our mods after a month or two is the real issue here. But anyway, thank you for the information.

‘I suspect that a "prestigious" journal has usable tools or they wouldn't merit their reputation.’ — If only this were always true!  As Dan Romik’s answer says, publishers (especially large corporate ones) often outsource production editing to third-party contractors, who are often completely lacking in subject-matter expertise.  The very worst contractors (like OP’s situation) presumably don’t last long, but I’ve seen serious journals persist for years with production-editing processes that are just barely fit-for-purpose, and a huge headache for authors.

'I suspect that a "prestigious" journal has usable tools or they wouldn't merit their reputation.' [citation needed]

@CaptainEmacs, a citation for my suspicion?

@Buffy Of course, linking the citation request to your suspicion was more to humorous effect. The statement that a journal has useable tools or wouldn't merit their reputation is provably wrong, I have encountered that very good journals had very questionable tools. They survive by their reputation, not their tools.
